# Additional config files

Tags: c#

I have loaded the default `App.config` file in my solution and I'm able to access stored variables from it.

**XML**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" ?>
<configuration>
  <appSettings>
    <add key="foo" value="bar"/>
  </appSettings>
</configuration>
```

**C#**

```
Configuration configManager = ConfigurationManager.OpenExeConfiguration(ConfigurationUserLevel.None);
KeyValueConfigurationCollection config = configManager.AppSettings.Settings;
string foo = config["foo"].Value;
```

Now I have created another configuration file to store variables for another part of my solution, but I can't figure out how to load it the same way with [ConfigurationManager](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.configuration.configurationmanager(v=vs.110).aspx).

```
Configuration config2 = ConfigurationManager.OpenExeConfiguration("path/to/config.config");
```

Comment: what happens as you tried? would [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/a/12587078/1132334) help?

Comment: Why don't you just use a custom file for setting your configs?

Comment: Did you set the property of the config file as `Build action = Content` and `Copy to Output Directory = Copy if newer` (or something) ?

Answer (score 1):

Perhaps you are looking for this:

```
ExeConfigurationFileMap exeConfigurationFileMap = new ExeConfigurationFileMap();
exeConfigurationFileMap.ExeConfigFilename = "your file path here";
Configuration customConfig = ConfigurationManager.OpenMappedExeConfiguration(exeConfigurationFileMap, ConfigurationUserLevel.None);
```

Comment: I'm not able to test this right now -- would the`ExeConfigFilename` attribute be set to the path to the .config file?

Comment: Yes. it should be the path to config file

Comment: Thanks. I will give this a go when I'm back at my desk